# document.getElementById() select other browsers element

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-sync

I am facing a very strange cross-browser behavior with javascript where code is called with the same page opened in different browsers (*Firefox*, *Chrome* and *Safari* in my case).

I tried to write the simplest code to reproduce it below. When hooking the `onclick` event for a button, I log something to the console and add a `<p>` element to the page:

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() {
    console.log('click');
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var t = document.createTextNode('click happened');
    p.appendChild(t);
    content.appendChild(p);
};
```

```html
<button id="click">click</button>
<div id='content'></button>
```

With two or three browser opened on the same page, the event is fired in all windows.

I must precise I serve my code with https://browsersync.io:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "*.html, *.css, *.js"
```

What is going wrong? Is it a normal behavior?

### My configuration

- *MacOS 10.11.6 (11602.2.14.0.7)*
- *Safari 10.0.1*
- *Firefox 50.1.0*
- *Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)*
- *browser-sync 2.18.5*

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What browser(s) are you experiencing this issue with (browser and version please)? This behavior seems highly unlikely.

Comment: um, that should not be possible....

Comment: I know for a fact that this is not possible (by design for security reasons), but I just tested your code for ha, ha's and opened it in several browser tabs simultaneously. As expected, what happens on one page has no effect on the others.

Comment: I agree this behavior is unlikely to happen, and I quite worried to reproduce it with the 3 main browsers...

Comment: I tried to push it in a github page and the problem doesn't happen. I must precise I serve my code with `browser-sync start --server --files "*.html, *.css, *.js"`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but a feature of [browsersync.io](https://browsersync.io) !!!